# jquery assigning click function from a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, click

It's an old project that i'm updating so is not th prettiest of coding.

I am trying to adapt a plugin for my specific needs, the plugin in question is a simple colapsible panel plugin.

I want to be able to style each panel with a different color depending on the rel that is assigned to the div.

its actually php code that generates the css and the code for the div, i then call jquery to apply the collapsible panel plugin.

it styles everything ok but the click function does not work, any pointers would be most helpfull: am thinking i need to apply .delegate() somewhere but not sure how to.

The url: http://www.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/NEW%20Search/fullsearch_rework.php
To get test results: click [choose all] above the select borough selector and click the search button.

the code that creates the panel:

```
//all this is wrapped in a php loop:
<style type="text/css">
            .C_<?php echo $myCurrentBorough ?>_color{
               color:<?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['color']; ?>;
               font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
               font-size:12px;
               letter-spacing:1px;
               text-transform:uppercase; 
               font-weight: bold;   
            }
            .collapsibleContainer<?php echo $myCurrentBorough ?>{
                     border: solid 0px <?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['color']; ?>;
                }

                .collapsibleContainerTitle<?php echo $myCurrentBorough ?>{
                     cursor:pointer;
                     color:#000000;
                     background-color:<?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['color']; ?>
                }

                .collapsibleContainerTitle div<?php echo $myCurrentBorough ?>{
                     padding-top:5px;
                     padding-left:10px;
                     background-color:<?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['color']; ?>;
                     color:#607882;
                }

                .collapsibleContainerContent<?php echo $myCurrentBorough ?>{
                     padding: 10px;
                     background-color:<?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['color']; ?>;
                }

         </style>
        <?php if($boroughCounter > 0){?>

             <div class="collapsibleContainer<?php echo $myCurrentBorough; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $myCurrentBorough; ?>" title="Locations Found In <?php echo $row_rs_myBoroughs['Borough_Name']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $myCurrentBorough; ?>">
            MY DIV CONTENT GOES HERE
               </div>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $(".collapsibleContainer<?php echo $myCurrentBorough; ?>").collapsiblePanel();
                        });
                    </script>
                    <?php } //end check to see if locations exist in borough?>
```

The jquery plugin:

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
            // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
            return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-widget");
    // Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='collapsibleContainerContent"+$(this).attr("rel")+" ui-widget-content' rel='"+$(this).attr("rel")+"'></div>");

    // Create a new div as the first item within the container.  Put the title of the panel in here.
    $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle"+$(this).attr("rel")+" ui-widget-header'><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));

    // Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new title div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle"+$(this).attr("rel")+"", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick());
}

function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick(myID) {
    // The item clicked is the title div... get this parent (the overall container) and toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent"+$(this).attr("rel")+"", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click method is invoking the function, instead of passing a reference to the function. Remove the () and the event will trigger.

CURRENT CODE:
$(".collapsibleContainerTitle"+$(this).attr("rel")+"", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick**()**);

FIXED CODE:
$(".collapsibleContainerTitle"+$(this).attr("rel")+"", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried your suggested code but still does not open/close the panels when clicked

Comment: ive added a console.log to the click and the right parent is displayed in the console, seems strange why it does not work

Comment: $(".collapsibleContainerContent"+$(this).parent().parent().attr("rel")).toggle()

Comment: The first issue is that the selector was not finding the correct DOM element. The second issue is that slideToggle() is not working...I'm not sure what is wrong...but toggle() works.

Comment: still not liking it, wish i understood the console output!

Comment: You are using an older version of jquery 1.3.2...I don't know if that makes a difference or not. You could try upgrading to 1.4.X and see if it helps. Are you using firebug, that is tool I used to track down the bugs?

Comment: got it i had forgotton to put the rel into the header div that getrs clicked!!! ` $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle"+$(this).attr("rel")+" ui-widget-header' rel='"+$(this).attr("rel")+"'><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));` now it works thanks

Comment: yeah i use firebug is especially usefull would be lost without it!